# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. after live hosting nodejs application

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, cyclic

trying to make a post request but i keep getting this error in my front end

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sore-rose-chiton-tam.cyclic.app/api/blogs' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

i'm using cyclic to host my nodejs app this the error i get in cyclic console

```
2023-04-03 09:44:11.420: [ERROR] Process timed out after 30 seconds.
```

this how i use cors

```
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions ={
  origin:'http://localhost:8080',
  credentials:true,           
  optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

it works fine on local host please how can i go about this

Comment: "Process timed out after 30 seconds" suggests the problem is that your code is failing to generate a response in time, so the CORS set up becomes irrelevant. You should address that instead.

Comment: @Quentin  its an email scheduler ,is there a way i have have a loader to keep loading to avoid the time out